# Suppress web browser launch by external programs

Tags: windows-7

Sometimes, crappy Windows software (Java installer for example) wants to open a website without asking.
Is there any way to suppress this behavior?

Or better: A configurable rule set of processes which are (not) allowed to launch a certain program like:

```
rule opera.exe
 if caller != explorer.exe then
   suppress()
endrule
```

I'm using windows 7.

Comment: Theoretically you could write a tool that would register as a browser and ask you about every single link or filter them in some way. I'm not sure if it's possible to pinpoint the process that tries to open that link.

Comment: Interesting idea.Theres a tool called "Exe Radar" from novirusthanks.org which does something similar like I described above but it doesn't allow filtering for the caller. So I think its possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a third party solution like [Process Blocker](http://www.processblocker.com/). Its free and does a very good job. It also compares CRC for added security.

[image]

I have always despised Internet Explorer and see no reason to ever use it.

Hope this may help resolve your issue. :)